# Intuitively explain Bi-linear time frequency distributions, someone please?

Tags: transform

I have a fairly good understanding of Wavelet Analysis, but what are these bilinear distributions and how do they differ from Wavelet Transform?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned - all these methods share common principle, they allow for representation of our signal in time-frequency domain. First thing to notice is that wavelets are very different from the STFT-like (linear) methods as they provide scale dependent frequency resolution (which in case of STFT is constant and governed by Heisenberg uncertainty principle). Probably you've seen this famous picture:

[image]

So called bi-linear transform mostly refers to Wigner Transform which can be considered as the Fourier Transform of signals' instantaneous autocorrelation function. It is governed by following equation:

$$W(t,f)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \left( t+ \frac{\tau}{2} \right) x^* \left( t-\frac{\tau}{2} \right) e^{-2\pi i f \tau} d\tau$$

where $^*$ denotes complex conjugate and $\tau$ is the time delay.

One might notice that in analogy to STFT, the shifted signal itself is considered as a window. It is also worth of mentioning, that Wigner Transform provides **perfect time and frequency resolution at the same time** - this is simply great for signals with fast changes of instantaneous frequency. On the other hand WT is the bi-linear transform, which implies major disadvantage: for each linear combination of two signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, result consists of two parts: auto-terms and **cross-terms**. This issue produces interferences in time-frequency representation known as "beats", which can make interpretation of WT difficult. If you are looking for more specific mathematical description, then please refer to article posted below - I see no point in rewriting equations.

Example is shown on a figure below, where two linear chirps were analysed. Cross-term is clearly visible in between, which makes interpretation of results troublesome. Sometimes it happens, that magnitude of cross-term is even higher than auto-terms.

[image]

Although some methods were described in literature how to deal with this problem. Please refer to the following article for more details.

> [R.B. Pachori and P. Sircar - *A new technique to reduce cross terms in the Wigner distribution*](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F229062547_A_new_technique_to_reduce_cross_terms_in_the_Wigner_distribution%2Ffile%2F72e7e526e15fc3627a.pdf&ei=n9SVU_jYAuic0AWzu4HIDA&usg=AFQjCNEE53Qk9GHWJknSCCYtNh1gy2WyGg&sig2=rK8hGvi3QoHNk1SEL6GCPg&bvm=bv.68445247,d.ZGU&cad=rja)